# Tracking a child state change in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, render, viewmodel, tracking, children

I have a component whose purpose is to display a list of items and let the user select one or more of the items.

This component is populated from a backend API and fed by a parent component with `props`.

However, since the data passed from the prop doesn't have the format I want, I need to transform it and provide a viewmodel with a computed property.

I'm able to render the list and handle selections by using `v-on:click`, but when I set `selected=true` the list is not updated to reflect the change in state of the child.

I assume this is because children property changes are not tracked by Vue.js and I probably need to use a watcher or something, but this doesn't seem right. It seems too cumbersome for a trivial operation so I must assume I'm missing something.

Here's the full repro: https://codesandbox.io/s/1q17yo446q

By clicking on Plan 1 or Plan 2 you will see it being selected in the console, but it won't reflect in the rendered list.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `vm` is a computed property.

If you want it to be reactive, you you have to declare it upfront, empty.
Read more here: [reactivity in depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html).

Here's your example [working](https://codesandbox.io/s/91rln3w54o).

Alternatively, if your `member` is coming from parent component, through `propsData` (i.e.: `:member="member"`), you want to move the mapper from `beforeMount` in a `watch` on `member`. For example:

```
propsData: {
  member: {
    type: Object,
    default: null
  }
},
data: () => ({ vm: {}}),
watch: {
  member: {
    handler(m) {
      if (!m) { this.vm = {}; } else {
        this.vm = {
          memberName: m.name,
          subscriptions: m.subscriptions.map(s => ({ ...s }))
        };
      }
    },
    immediate: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have read the guide part you sent before, but somehow I missed that explanation. There's one extra thing I'd like to ask. To me, it seems that if you bind that that is always there, or that reside into the component itself, the implementation is completely natural. When you do what I'm trying to, which is create a viewmodel (to apply transformations on the "raw" data) it requires a "lot " of boilerplate accessory code. Is that really true or am I missing something else?

Comment: The way to go is to always normalize the data the moment you loaded it from API, so it always has the same format throughout your app. You obviously will need the inverse, when you want to save your items. A good rule of thumb is to prefix your computed properties with a particular signature (I use `_`) and to strip all those from the object before sending it back.

Comment: Taking my component as an example, the data that it receives from props doesn't have the "Selected" property I added in the VM (looking at my code sample it is there, but it should not be, my mistake). You are saying that my component should receive the data in the way it "wants" instead of the raw data that would be modified by a computed/watcher prop? In other words, leave all the transformation for the parent who fetched the data from the API and passes onto the child? I thought about it, but I "don't like" the idea of exposing the components "logic" and leaking internal behavior. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes. Your method to get data should map it the format you want it using a `.then( r => r.map(...))` if it uses a Promise fetcher (http.post) or in a `.pipe(map(r => r.map(...)))` if it uses an Observable fetcher (http.postObservable). Which means whenever you call that method the `then()`/`subscribe()` always has the data in the format you want it. There's no point in computing it inside each component using it.

Comment: Thanks for the conversation! I ended up doing something different since I just need one item selected. I went "around" and just keep the selected instance inside the component with no need to create a VM. With this, I have my encapsulation preserved :) In case you are curious here's how I did it: https://codesandbox.io/s/1q17yo446q